# No input file specified in Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I'm creating a Laravel project with Vagrant and Homestead. Whenever I create a project mapped to a '**Laravel**' directory/project name, it works. However, I encounter problems whenever I remove the '**Laravel**' want to use a different project name. So I'm mapping it correctly but I still receive the 'No input file' message. Here are my specs:

**PHP -v**

```
PHP 5.5.15RC1 (cli) (built: Jul 15 2014 11:14:55)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

**Homestead.yaml (The working verison)**

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: /Users/name/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - /Users/name/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/name/Homestead/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public


variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

To really drag out this explanation, here is the line of the homestead.yaml file I change for a different project name

```
sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/RANDOM_PROJECT_NAME/public
```

Nothing else is changed except for when I create a new Laravel project in the Code through Composer.

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1):

Try `serve` -script (located in /vagrant/scripts, should be added to PATH also) and you don't need to change anything on Homestead.yaml (unless there are some black magick which would update host machines `hosts` -file automatically).

Updating Homestead.yaml probably requires re-provisioning VM anyway.

Comment: Yes, I have to use the serve script and now it works.